# Error the docker engine version is less than the minimum

Tags: docker, centos, vagrant

I want to make a vm system with Vagrant and docker.

This is my Vagrant file.

---

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "centos/6"
config.vm.provision "docker"
config.vm.synced_folder "./docker", "/tmp/docker", type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: ".svn/"
$get_compose = <<-'EOF'
    curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
    sudo mv docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
    sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/docker-compose
    sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
EOF
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $get_compose
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "docker-compose -f /tmp/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d", run: "always"
end
```

But, This fail on last line with this message.
The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0 or greater.

So, I Checked docker version, and it was 1.7.1

When i tried to Vagrant up With same vagrantfile just edited from centos/6 to centos/7.
It was work Successfully.

The docker version which installed in centos/7 was greater than 1.7.1.

Now I understand mean of this error message.

But, I have to install centos/6 and I don't know how can i solve this.

Somebody know to specify docker version on config.vm.provision "docker" Or update docker version?

Please teach me if you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker only supports CentOS 7: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/.

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much! I will suggest to install centos/7 to boss. Thank you